# JavaFX2.0 fx-pref-width not working

Tags: javafx

I use JavaFX2.0 to my java application, then I use `.fxml` file to build my UI, then I use css to decorate button or label.

Just like:

```
/* JavaFX CSS - Leave this comment until you have at least create one rule which uses -fx-Property */

.lebel{
      -fx-alignment: center ;
      -fx-pref-width:20% ;
      -fx-pref-height: 180 ;
      -fx-background-color: transparent ;
      -fx-text-fill: white ;
      -fx-background-size: stretch;
      -fx-padding: 0 0;
      -fx-font-size: 20sp;
   }
```

Five labels are placed horizontally, but the property `-fx-pref-width:20%` doesn't work on the UI. I am trying to use `-fx-pref-width:%` to design UI for different sizes of stage.

Comment: After compiling it never gets to it the size we give ! Once your code is converted to jar file and when you execute that you will see your defined length and height of window! Same problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-fx-pref-width` is defined by `Region`. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).

This is the abstract from it:

> Property: -fx-min-width, -fx-pref-width, -fx-max-width
>
> Values: < number >
>
> Default: -1
>
> Comments: Percentage values are not useful since the actual value would be computed from the width and/or height of the Region's parent before the parent is laid out.

So, percentages are not supported. You would need to do it using code via binding perhaps.

Comment: does it have  property “weight” like android?

Comment: @Lawas Not that I'm aware of. You can wrap them into a `Pane` with such feature, such as `GridPane`, which can specify percentages on the columns/rows. `TilePane` might also be what you need, which would size all the children to the same size.